# left join two separate queries

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have two separate queries which pretty much return the same thing:

```
select id 
from t 
where id<>'' 
GROUP BY id 
having count(*) >= 2;

select id 
from t2 
where id is not null 
GROUP BY id 
having count(*) >= 2 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

a list of ids whose values appear more than once. The first query returns more than the second, So I need to left join them somehow to get the results that are in the first query but not in the second. I tried to do a left join but it is not working properly.

I also tried the following to no avail:

```
select id 
from t 
where id<>'' 
GROUP BY id 
having count(*) >= 2 
  not in (select id from t2 where id is not null GROUP BY id having count(*) >= 2 
          ORDER BY id ASC)
```

**Additional Info**

Query one is giving me all ids that have the same value for table 1 and query 2 is giving me all the same value ones for table 2. There are additional gotchas like there are some blank ids in table one while there are some nulls in table 2, hence the conditions excluding blanks for the former and nulls for the latter. So I get back these two separate results, which are almost the same, except in results 1 there are claims that arent in results 2 **but only when these queries are run** because they are duplicated in table 1 but not in table 2. although they do exist in table 2. So a simple left join where t1.id <> t2.id will not work because they do exist in t2.

[image]

Comment: What do you *actually* want the query to do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills give me the ones in my first query that are not in the second.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id, t2.id FROM t 
LEFT OUTER JOIN t2
ON t.id <> t2.id
WHERE t.id<>'' 
GROUP BY t.id having count(t.id) >= 2 
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

I assume your **not in** part before the subquery is actually mean that the id from the table t and t2 are not same and so added the condition *t.id <> t2.id*

**EDIT**

```
SELECT t.id  FROM t 
WHERE t.id<>''
AND t.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM t2  where id is not null )
GROUP BY t.id having count(t.id) >= 2 
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f95a73/5)

Comment: it runs forever :-/ and doesnt return anything

Comment: @EduardoDennis Check my Updated query(Edit part).

Comment: but lets say you add one 4 to the second one it doesnt return 4 in the results. But its supposed to since 4 in the second is there only once I am trying to get back only values that are duplicates in the first table that are not duplicates in the second regardless if they appear once or not.

Answer (score 1):

You want to select ids in `t1` that are not in `t2`.  `JOIN` on `t2` and ensure that the result is `NULL`.

```
SELECT t.id
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(t.id) > 1
```

Comment: but I need it only for ones that are more than count is more than 2, so basically those extra conditions ?

Comment: @EduardoDennis you mean ids in t1 not in t2 of which there are more than one in t1?

Comment: check out additional info I posted, sorry about the vagueness of my original post.

Comment: @EduardoDennis see edit; is there a key on `id` for both tables?